How to set the plot height in Apexcharts?
I'm using Apexcharts (with Vue) to create a Pie chart, but I can't set the height specifically for the pie/plot area.
The docs describe the options.chart.height property, but that is used to set the height for the whole element. So it will also set the height for the legend wrapper.

const options = {
  chart: {
    height: 98,
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true
    },
    parentHeightOffset: 0,
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  theme: {
    monochrome: {
      enabled: true
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      customScale: 1,
      expandOnClick: false,
      offsetX: -64,
      donut: {
        size: 0,
        labels: {
          show: false,
        }
      }
    }
  },
  stroke: {
    show: false,
  },
  legend: {
    show: true,
    formatter: function(seriesName, opts) {
      return [`<span class="wtb-alocation__chart-legend-item">${seriesName} • <strong>${opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex] * 100}%</strong></span>`]
    },
    offsetX: 40,
    offsetY: 0,
    markers: {
      width: 4,
      height: 4,
      radius: 4,
    },
    onItemClick: {
        toggleDataSeries: true
    },
    onItemHover: {
        highlightDataSeries: true
    },
    height: '100%',
  },
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
        chart: {
          height: 98,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};

<VueApexCharts type="donut" :options="options" :series="series" />

